# Get query results even with null foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a query in which I have multiple relationships.

The foreign key `acquirente_corretor_id` can be null or not. If it is different from `null`, it has a relationship with the `dobby` table.

I have the following query, but it only works for `acquirente_corretor_id` that is not `null`. Only displays the result with this key other than `null`.

One more thing, you only query the acquirer relationship if the variables `$empresa_recebedora`, `$acquirente`, and `$serial` are different from `null`.

How can I make that possible? I've tried different forms of querying and it doesn't work.

```php
$contratos = Contrato::with([
    'parcela',
    'cliente',
    'status',
    'operador',
    'tabela',
    'adquirente',
    'bancos',
    'bancos.empresa',
    'bancos.banco',
    'adquirente'
])
    ->whereHas('cvs', function ($q) use ($cv) {
        if (!is_null($cv)) {
            $q->where('cv', $cv);
        }
    })
    ->whereHas('bancos', function ($q) use ($banco, $empresa_pagadora) {
        if (!is_null($banco)) {
            $q->where('banco_id', $banco);
        }
        if (!is_null($empresa_pagadora)) {
            $q->where('empresa_id', $empresa_pagadora);
        }
    })
    ->whereHas('cliente', function ($q) use ($cliente) {
        if (!is_null($cliente)) {
            $q->where('nome', 'LIKE', "%{$cliente}%");
        }
    })
    ->whereHas('adquirente.maquineta.empresa', function ($q) use ($empresa_recebedora) {
        if (!is_null($empresa_recebedora)) {
            $q->where('empresa_id', $empresa_recebedora);
        }
    })
    ->whereHas('adquirente.maquineta.adquirente', function ($q) use ($adquirente) {
        if (!is_null($adquirente)) {
            $q->where('adquirente_id', $adquirente);
        }
    })
    ->whereHas('adquirente.maquineta', function ($q) use ($serial) {
        if (!is_null($serial)) {
            $q->where('numero_serie', $serial);
        }
    })
    ->when($status, function ($query, $status) {
        $query->whereIn('contratos.status_id', $status);
    })
    ->when($ca, function ($query, $ca) {
        $query->where('contratos.conciliacao_adquirente', $ca);
    })
    ->when($cb, function ($query, $cb) {
        $query->where('contratos.conciliacao_bancaria', $cb);
    })
    ->when($operador, function ($query, $operador) {
        $query->where('contratos.operador_id', $operador);
    })
    ->when($multiplicador, function ($query, $multiplicador) {
        $query->where('contratos.multiplicador_id', $multiplicador);
    })
    ->when($gerente, function ($query, $gerente) {
        $query->where('contratos.gerente_id', $gerente);
    })
    ->when($indicador, function ($query, $indicador) {
        $query->where('contratos.indicador_id', $indicador);
    })
    ->when($valor_liquido, function ($query, $valor_liquido) {
        $query->where('contratos.valor_liquido', 'LIKE', "{$valor_liquido}%");
    })
    ->where(function ($query) use ($inicio, $fim) {
        if (!is_null($inicio) && !is_null($fim)) {
            $query->whereBetween('data_operacao', [$inicio, $fim]);
        }
    })                    
    ->orderBy($request->sortField, $sortOrder)
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($query) {
        $pagadoras = $query->bancos;
        foreach ($pagadoras as $pagadora) {
            $empresas[] = $pagadora->empresa['nome'];
            $bancos[] = $pagadora->banco['nome'];
            $recebedores[] = $pagadora->cpf . ' - ' . $pagadora->nome;
        }

        $cvs = $query->cvs;
        foreach ($cvs as $codigo) {
            $codigos[] = $codigo->cv;
        }

        $query->empresas_pagadoras = implode(', ', $empresas);
        $query->bancos_pagadores = implode(', ', $bancos);
        $query->lista_codigos = implode(', ', $codigos);
        $query->recebedores = implode(', ', $recebedores);
    });
```

I tried solving it this way, but I got the following error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::acquirente()

```
$contratos = Contrato::with([
    'parcela',
    'cliente',
    'status',
    'operador',
    'tabela',
    'bancos',
    'bancos.empresa',
    'bancos.banco',
    'adquirente'
])
    ->whereHas('cvs', function ($q) use ($cv) {
        if (!is_null($cv)) {
            $q->where('cv', $cv);
        }
    })
    ->whereHas('bancos', function ($q) use ($banco, $empresa_pagadora) {
        if (!is_null($banco)) {
            $q->where('banco_id', $banco);
        }
        if (!is_null($empresa_pagadora)) {
            $q->where('empresa_id', $empresa_pagadora);
        }
    })
    ->whereHas('cliente', function ($q) use ($cliente) {
        if (!is_null($cliente)) {
            $q->where('nome', 'LIKE', "%{$cliente}%");
        }
    })
    ->whereHas('adquirente', function ($q) use ($empresa_recebedora, $adquirente, $serial) {
        $q->whereHas('adquirente.maquineta.empresa', function ($q) use ($empresa_recebedora) {
            if (!is_null($empresa_recebedora)) {
                $q->where('empresa_id', $empresa_recebedora);
            }
        })
            ->whereHas('adquirente.maquineta.adquirente', function ($q) use ($adquirente) {
                if (!is_null($adquirente)) {
                    $q->where('adquirente_id', $adquirente);
                }
            })
            ->whereHas('adquirente.maquineta', function ($q) use ($serial) {
                if (!is_null($serial)) {
                    $q->where('numero_serie', $serial);
                }
            });
    })
    ->when($status, function ($query, $status) {
        $query->whereIn('contratos.status_id', $status);
    })
    ->when($ca, function ($query, $ca) {
        $query->where('contratos.conciliacao_adquirente', $ca);
    })
    ->when($cb, function ($query, $cb) {
        $query->where('contratos.conciliacao_bancaria', $cb);
    })
    ->when($operador, function ($query, $operador) {
        $query->where('contratos.operador_id', $operador);
    })
    ->when($multiplicador, function ($query, $multiplicador) {
        $query->where('contratos.multiplicador_id', $multiplicador);
    })
    ->when($gerente, function ($query, $gerente) {
        $query->where('contratos.gerente_id', $gerente);
    })
    ->when($indicador, function ($query, $indicador) {
        $query->where('contratos.indicador_id', $indicador);
    })
    ->when($valor_liquido, function ($query, $valor_liquido) {
        $query->where('contratos.valor_liquido', 'LIKE', "{$valor_liquido}%");
    })
    ->where(function ($query) use ($inicio, $fim) {
        if (!is_null($inicio) && !is_null($fim)) {
            $query->whereBetween('data_operacao', [$inicio, $fim]);
        }
    })
    ->orderBy($request->sortField, $sortOrder)
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($query) {
        $pagadoras = $query->bancos;
        foreach ($pagadoras as $pagadora) {
            $empresas[] = $pagadora->empresa['nome'];
            $bancos[] = $pagadora->banco['nome'];
            $recebedores[] = $pagadora->cpf . ' - ' . $pagadora->nome;
        }

        $cvs = $query->cvs;
        foreach ($cvs as $codigo) {
            $codigos[] = $codigo->cv;
        }

        $query->empresas_pagadoras = implode(', ', $empresas);
        $query->bancos_pagadores = implode(', ', $bancos);
        $query->lista_codigos = implode(', ', $codigos);
        $query->recebedores = implode(', ', $recebedores);
    });
```